# Vector of shared_ptr of a abstract bass class pointing to derived classes

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I am in a class where I am supposed to create a vector of shared pointers with an abstract base class and a two level hierarchy for derived classes.

```
class Base
{
   virtual string returnName() = 0;
};

class DerivedOne : public Base
{
private:
   string name;

public:
   DerivedOne()
   {name = "Derived";}

   virtual string returnName()
   {return name;}
};

class DerivedTwo : public DerivedOne
{
private:
   string secondName;

public:
   DerivedTwo()
   {secondName  = "DerivedTwo";}

   virtual string returnName()
   {return secondName;}
};

int main()
{
   vector<shared_ptr<Base>> entities;
   entities.push_back(new DerivedOne());

   return 0;
}
```

My issue is with adding a derived class to the end of the vector using the `push_back()` and when compiling it says `no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base> >::push_back(DerivedOne*)`

How would I add an initialized derived class to the vector?

Comment: You can make it work by casting raw pointer to `std::shared_ptr` as `std::shared_ptr` ctor is explicit. But you better use `std::make_shared()` anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using a raw `new` at all.  Instead, you should use `std::make_shared` to allocate your objects that will be managed by `std::shared_ptr`s:

```
entities.push_back(std::make_shared<DerivedOne>());
```

`std::make_shared` returns a `std::shared_ptr` to the newly allocated object rather than a raw pointer.  Not only that make `std::vector::push_back` work in this case, it's also less likely to leak memory in the face of exceptions.

Comment: That worked. Would you only use the raw `new` with raw pointers?

Comment: Raw `new` returns a raw pointer, and you should avoid using raw pointers whenever possible.  There are very few reasons to ever use `new` directly in modern C++.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to replace this line with

```
entities.emplace_back(new DerivedOne());
```

because you don't want to `push_back` a `Base*` but rather a `std::shared_ptr<Base>`. Using `emplace` will allow the `Base*` to be used in the constructor of `std::shared_ptr<Base>` which is then added to your vector.

Comment: I don't think that this works, because a `shared_ptr` cannot be constructed from a raw pointer implicitly.

Comment: @j6t it compiles https://ideone.com/yKrRUk but it is better to call `std::make_shared()` anyway

Comment: @j6t There certainly is a constructor for `std::shared_ptr<T>(T*)` see [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Comment: I think @j6t meant that it would not because such ctor is explicit

Comment: @Slava I see. The reason why it works is because behind the scenes, `emplace()` has to call `new (addr) std::shared_ptr<Base>(arg)`, and that is sufficiently explicit, so that this `explicit` constructor is viable.